# Dynamic reference of assembly in SSIS script task

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, .net-assembly, epplus-4

Currently, I am using `EPPlus dll` in my `SSIS script task` to generate excel reports and everything is working fine. I have managed to do away with the part to add the `dll` into `GAC` by loading the custom assemblies into the `SSIS script task` itself.

Took help from this [link](http://roman.tumaykin.com/tools/2015/12/09/Loading-custom-assemblies-into-SSIS-Script-Task-without-installing-them-into-GAC-Part-2.html).

So, everything is sorted out in my development system as of now.

Now what I want to know is if my move this `SSIS` package to a different system (ex:- other colleague, QA environment, PROD environment etc...) is there a need to download the EPPlus dll for each system and open up the `SSIS` package make a reference to the assembly build the solution and then ready to deploy.

**Edit**: I just tried in one my colleague's system and I had to download the dll and make a reference of it in the `SSIS script task`.
So, is this the only possible way or am I missing something?

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/) suggests that you drop your dll in a shared location and use a package variable to refer to that path in your script task. Would that help?

Comment: I have already done that, GAC part is taken care